# Does order of methods within a class matter?

Tags: python, oop, methods, constructor

My problems or rather my misunderstanding are next.

**First one:**

Basically i made my linked list class, and now as you can see in following code in constructor i called append method before it was actually created and the code run without  an error, so i am really interested to know why i didn't encountered any error there.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


class Linkedlist:
    def __init__(self, *value):
        if len(value) == 1:
            new_node = Node(value[0])
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            self.lenght = 1
        else:
            self.__init__(value[0])
            other_values = value[1::]
            for i in other_values:
                self.append(i)
        print('test1')


    def append(self, *value):
        for i in value:
            new_node = Node(i)
            if self.head == None:
                self.head = new_node
                self.tail = new_node
            else:
                self.tail.next = new_node
                self.tail = new_node
                self.lenght += 1
            print('test2')

        return True
```

Second one:

As you can see i left print function in both constructor and append method in order to see how things are going.  when i execute next code:

```
my_linked_list = Linkedlist(3, 2, 7, 9)
```

i get the output as following: test1, test2, test2, test2, test1 and i was expecting only test2, test2, test2, test1, i am curious why does it print test1 first.

Sorry if my question was too long. I am quite new to programming and really curious about a lot of things. Answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are recursively calling `Linkedlist.__init__` before any of the calls to `Linkedlist.append`.

Answer (score 1):

Functions being defined is different from them being run; in your code, you define `__init__` before you define `append`, but you don't actually *call* append until later. By the time you call it, it's been defined.

For the order of prints, `__init__` is called implicitly when you create the LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `Linkedlist.__init__` includes a recursive call to `Likedlist.__init__`. You don't need that, nor do you need to treat a single argument as a special case. You can simply write

```
def __init__(self, *values):
    self.length = 0

    for v in values:
        self.append(v)
```

You'll need to adjust `append` slightly to ensure that `self.length` is *always* incremented, even if the list was originally empty.

`append` becomes even simpler if you define your list to always include a dummy node that `self.head` references. You can store the length in this node.

```
def __init__(self, *values):
    self.head = self.tail = Node(0)
    for v in values:
        self.append(v)
```

I leave it as an exercise to write `append` under this assumption.